# Probability theory, determine the distribution of $X+Y$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Recently I tried to solve a question in probability theory but did not get quite the same answer as the conclusion and would like to understand where I am wrong somewhere. The question reads:

> Suppose that $(X,Y)^\prime$ has density $f(x)=\frac{2}{(1+x+y)^3}$ for
> $x,y > 0$ and $0$ otherwise. Determine the distribution of $X+Y$.

So, I started to solve the problem and used $U=X+Y$ as well as $V=Y$, which implies that $X=U-V$ and $Y=V$. We can call $g^{-1}(U,V)=(U-V,V)$. We then find the Jacobian for $g^{-1}(U,V)$ and this becomes equal to 1. We now have everything we need and can begin to produce the distribution for $f_{U,V}(u,v)$:$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=\frac{2}{(1+(u-v)+v)^3}=\frac{2}{(1+u)^3}.$$

Finally, since we are looking for the distribution of $X+Y$ and $U=X+Y$, we obtain the marginal density for U: $$f_U(u)=\int f_{U,V}(u,v)dv=\int \frac{2}{(1+u)^3}dv=\frac{2}{(1+u)^3}\int dv=\frac{2v}{(1+u)^3}.$$

But, according to the answer in the textbook the solution should be $\frac{2u}{(1+u)^3}$ and I cannot see why and would appreciate any help in getting a better understanding of this. I suspect I'm missing something in the integral, but can't find anything to help me understand what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\Because $U=X-Y, V=X$, then $\{X>0,Y>0\}$ means that $\{U>V, V>0\}$, so …

$$\begin{align}f_{\small U,V}(u,v)&=\dfrac{2}{(1+u)^3}\mathbf 1_{u>v>0}\\[2ex] f_U(u)&=\int_0^u\dfrac 2{(1+u)^3}~\mathbf 1_{u>0}~\mathrm d v\\ &=\dfrac{2u}{(1+u)^3}~\mathbf 1_{u>0}\end{align}$$